# No values in Excel after exporting from Java using Apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to export an excel from an java application here is my code but the problem is only last column values are appearing all other columns are empty as shown in this image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgvkR.jpg.

I'm using poi-3.10.1.

please suggest any changes do i need to make.

public class ExcelExport {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    File file = null;

    file = new File("D:/ExportExcel.xls");
    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
    Cell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);

    int row = 0;
    while (row < 5) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++) {
            cell = sheet.createRow(row).createCell(column);
            cell.setCellValue(row + "," + column);
        }
        row++;
    }
    workbook.write(fos);
    fos.close();
}
```

}

Comment: `sheet.createRow(row)` Creates a new empty row. So each loop you will have all values in that row deleted. Move this statement out of the `for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @BackSlash suggested, my code working fine

```
int row = 0;

while (row < 5) {
    Row r = sheet.createRow(row);
    for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++) {
        cell = r.createCell(column);
        cell.setCellValue(row + "," + column);
    }
    row++;
}
```